# Create onlineMeeting with API GRAPH - GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, api, graph, microsoft-graph-api, unauthorized

Frist i get the token.
After that, since i have the token i try to create a online meeting but i recieve this message:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings 401 (Unauthorized)

```
var token1="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
setMeeting();
function setMeeting(token1) {  
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'GET', 
 startDateTime:"2020-12-28T02:17:17.6491364Z",
  endDateTime:"2020-12-28T02:47:17.651138Z",
  subject:"Application Token Meeting",
  AutoAdmittedUsers: "Everyone",
  accessLevel: "everyone",
  entryExitAnnouncement: true,
  participants: {
    organizer: {
      identity: {
        user: {
          id: "EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM"
              }}} },
url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings",        headers: {  
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token1,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'  
        },  
    }).success(function(response) {  
        console.log(response); 

    }).error(function(error) {});  
}
```

Could you help me ?
I want to make a online meeting using javascript inside a framework.
If you have some examples please share.

Thanks

Comment: Please check the token using https://jwt.ms and see whether you implemented scopes/permissions to create online meeting or not.

Comment: In order to isolate the issue you can call the above API in Graph explorer or POSTMAN and see it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Javascript code that i used to create onlinemeetings (i used Graph SDK):

```js
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const onlineMeeting = {startDateTime:2020-11-26T14:30:34.2444915-07:00","endDateTime:2020-11-26T15:00:34.2464912-07:00","subject:"User Token Meeting"};

let res = await client.api('/me/onlineMeetings')
    .version('beta')
    .post(onlineMeeting);
```

The above code works for me. Adding response output for your view:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't use SDK.
I made some changes to my code.

```
var requestObjt = {
    audioConferencing : {
        "dialinUrl": "String",
        "ConferenceId": "String",
        "tollFreeNumber": "String",
        "tollNumber": "String"
    },
    
    creationDateTime: "Thu Nov 26 2020 16:30:00",
    endDateTime: "Thu Nov 26 2020 17:30:00",
    id: "12123",
    joinWebUrl: "123123", 
        participants: {
        organizer: {
            upn: "MAIL@domain.com",
            role: "presenter",
            identity: {
                "user": {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX",
                }
            }
        },
        "attendees": [
            {
                "upn": "MAIL@DOMAIN.com",
                "role": null,
                "identity": {
                    "user": {
                        "id": "XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX",
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "producers": [],
        "contributors": []
    },
    startDateTime:"Thu Nov 27 2020 16:30:00",
    subject: "migra",
    videoTeleconferenceId: "migra",
    isEntryExitAnnounced: "True",
    allowedPresenters: "Yes"
};

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings",
 /*   url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/create",*/
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestObjt),
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN','Content-Type': 'application/json'   },
    timeout: 500000,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(xhr);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

The answer i get is:

```
"{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "744fc2de-da4e-12zs-ba4c-4ac4a926ce96",
      "date": "2020-11-27T09:14:18",
      "client-request-id": "744fc2de-da4e-12zs-ba4c-4ac4a926ce96"
    }
  }
}"
```